# vsftpd can't start with command allow_writeable_chroot=YES

Tags: vsftpd

I had an error message when logging in with vsftpd.

```
500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()
```

I have found a solution on google that I have to add the following command to **vsftpd.conf**

```
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

But with this command added, I can not start vsftpd. What's wrong?

I'm using vsftpd 2.3.5

Comment: Can you please explain what does *I can not start vsftpd* mean? what did you try? what was the result?

Comment: I use this command service vsftpd restart, but vsftpd won't start if I have allow_writeable_chroot = YES in config file.  It looks like a bug in vsftpd 2.3.5 and is fixed in version 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using 12.04 LTS. You need to install vsftpd from [The Frontier Group PPA](https://launchpad.net/~thefrontiergroup/+archive/ubuntu/vsftpd):

> **PPA description**
>   vsftpd 2.3.5 with the allow_writeable_chroot feature backported from
>   vsftpd 3.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thefrontiergroup/vsftpd
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```

Comment: you are right, it seems to be a bug in version 2.3.5 and vsftpd 3 fixed this error.